# split ajax json response errors in each field

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

i used till now AJAX post with normal dataType 'html' , now i convert it and using dataType 'json' ,

Now before i used json i split response errors with for each span next to the input field .

this is my old ajax succses split errors code using normal datatype 'html' :

```
    success:
           function(data){

  var data_array = split('*');
                 for(var i=0; i<data_array.length-1; i++)
                 {
                    messgae_array = data_array[i].split(':');
                    $("#"+messgae_array[0]+"_error").html(messgae_array[1]);
                    $("#"+messgae_array[0]).css({"border":"1px solid red"});
                 }

}
```

this is my input on the form

```
<input type="text" id="uname" name="uname" value="" class="inplaceError" />
<span id="uname_error"></span>
```

i have more inputs i puted just ex how it look..

so every input i have span that holds the errors from the ajax response.

and now the problem is my old code know handle html response and not json response , i am javascript/ajax/json newbie , and i dont know how to change the split code so work with json response and not normal html response , any help please?

**Edit:**

i fire the errors like this :

```
   if(isset($_POST['p']) && !empty($_POST['p']))
    {
        if($password == $retype)
            {
            $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));
        // Create salted password (Careful with the chilli)
        $password = hash('sha512', $password.$random_salt);

        }
        else
        {
          $message['password']='&nbsp;password not match';
        }

and so on .

  $message['email']='&nbsp;wrong email';
```

and my foreach json array for the errors :

```
  foreach($message as $key => $val) {


          $return = array('error' => $key, 'message' => $val );
         echo json_encode($return);

           }
```

so somthing is wrong here with the foreach for the errors its fire wrong as the ajax response code any idea?

Comment: `var str="How are you doing today?";
var n=str.split(" ");` this is how split function is used .

Comment: data_array must be something like `var data_array= data.<attr>.split('*');`

Comment: @Husman Pedantic. Learned another new word, yay!

Comment: @rps: Ah the irony, of making a spelling mistake when correcting another. My bad!

Comment: Just to be pedantic, you spelt message wrong in messgae_array

Comment: @rps, "Learnt" - is the past tense of learn. "Learned" - describes a person with much knowledge. You learnt a new word to become a learned person. There you go, you learnt 2 more now.

Comment: @Husman O.O, and here I thought I had covered the grammar already! no,please don't find any more mistakes in this, I will be heart broken.

Comment: check my comment how your JSON data should be..

Answer (score 2):

You should not have to split strings in your data. If it is in the correct JSON format, you can access it easily using object notation (also possible via array notation):

```
var json = '{
  "someVar":true,
  "error":"my fatal error message"
}';

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert(obj.error);
```

This is why JSON was created, for ease of access and use. If you're still going to edit and split strings manually to read data from your JSON, you're doing it wrong.

EDIT:
Use nested json, if you need to identify and organise your messages.

```
var json = "errors": [{
        "id": "001",
        "field": "textfield1",
        "message": "message1."
    },
    {
        "id": "002",
        "field": "textfield2",
        "message": "message2."
    }];

    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

You can now apply styles to these fields, and display the messages:

```
foreach(obj.errors as err) {
  $("#"+err.field).html(err.message);
  $("#"+err.field).css({"border":"1px solid red"});
}
```

Comment: its good but not the same as i need ,as you see my code , i add css style and so on with foreach , but that foreach using normal datatype 'html' not json type ..

Comment: Yes, you can still do that. Your JSON object can contain multiple error messages, and can also keep references to the html elements or the id's or classes, You just need to structure your JSON correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
success:function(data)
        {
          // consider your data is like this JSON string
          // var data= [{"error":"uname","message":"&nbsp;wrong pass."},{"error":"email","message":"&nbsp;wrong name"}];
          // instead of this
          // var data_array = split('*');
          // use this

          //change your json parser to this
          var data_array = JSON.parse(data);
          for (var i in data_array )
          {
             $("#"+data_array[i].error+"_error").html(data_array[i].message);
             $("#"+data_array[i].error).css({"border":"1px solid red"});
          }    
}
```

Comment: thanks very better answer ! , but its not working :( but somthing like this i need..

Comment: check does that data get converted to data_array. that means JSON get parsed or not

Comment: yea i have the same json array : {"error":1,"message":"&nbsp;wrong email"}

Comment: your data must be something like this '{"uname":"user name is not valid","password":"Mandatory"}'

Comment: yea i did now still not working , what the diffrence mine the same no ? {"error":1,"message":"&nbsp;wrong email"}

Comment: my bad my response is liks that {"error":"uname","message":"&nbsp;wrong pass."}{"error":"email","message":"&nbsp;wrong name"}{"error":"password","message":"&nbsp;wrong user name"}{"error":"oldpassinp","message":"&nbsp;wrong email."}

Comment: your data as json string must be enclosed in [] and should be lide this [{err:msg},{err:msg}]. i have updated the answer.

Comment: yea i see thanks you very much ,can u help me fix my php side foreach code? iv edited my question

Comment: sry my frnd m not php guy...but make sure that your JSON string should be like this [{err:msg},{err:msg}] or like this [{err1:msg1,err2:msg2}], and its depends on how you create array at php code. is it one dimentional or two dimentional. depends on that u have to change code at client side

Comment: wait look i have this response now : {"oldpassinp":"&nbsp;\u05d4\u05e7\u05e9 \u05e1\u05d9\u05e1\u05de\u05d0 \u05e9\u05dc \u05d4\u05d7\u05e9\u05d1\u05d5\u05df \u05e9\u05d4\u05d9\u05e0\u05da \u05de\u05d7\u05d5\u05d1\u05e8 \u05d0\u05dc\u05d9\u05d5."} but its still not doing nothing

Comment: if your data variable look like this then u have to enclose this in [{"oldpassinp":"&nbsp;ghjgj"}] check latest ans..look for change in JSON.parse

Comment: hi if u here , i changed my php so now its working the same as u sayed but ur code still not working... any idea? this how look my json response : [{"error":"uname","message":"&nbsp;\u05e9\u05dd ."},{"error":"email","message":"&nbsp;\u05e9\u05dd \u05de\u05e9\u05ea\u05de\u05e9 \u05d0\u05d9\u05e0\u05d5 \u."},{"error":"password","message":"&nbsp;\u05e9\u05dd \u05de\u05e9\u05ea."},{"error":"oldpassinp","message":"&nbsp;\u05e9\u05dd \u05de\u05e9\u05ea."}]